# OneShot Iterable in Java

Tags: java

What is the name of the interface in Java that allows a single iteration? `Iterable` allows  multiple iterations AFAIK. My use case is below.

```
private static void iterateOverArray(double[] values) {
    OneShotIterable<Double> valuesIterable = Arrays.stream(values);
    oneShotIterate(valuesIterable);
}

private static void oneShotIterate(OneShotIterable<Double> valuesIterable) {
    for (double value : valuesIterable) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I know I can iterate over `double[] values` but I want to accept the most general input I can.

Comment: One single iteration does not require any loop. Just run your code.
So omit the for, just have the o stuff`

Comment: So you want every element to be accessible only once using your iterate method? Just store a boolean into your interface and set it to true after iterating over it?

Comment: Or you might be thinking about either a Stream or an Iterator?
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: If you want to iterate over the thing with an [enhanced `for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) (as you are doing in the method `oneShotIterate`) then it has to be `Iterable`. There is no "one-shot iterable" interface or other more general interface than `Iterable` in Java's standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific interface you desire, that supports a `for` loop and does not carry an implication of supporting multiple iterations, does *not exist* in Java.

`Iterator` and `Stream` are each single-use, but you must do some work to get them from an `Iterable`.

I am sorry if this is not the answer you hoped for, but it's the true answer.

Comment: "Does not exist" => to be precise, there is no such interface in Java's standard library, it's just not part of the design of collections or streams in the standard library.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this - an `Iterable` with only one item?

```
Iterable<Thing> iterable = java.util.Collections.singleton( myThing );
```

If you mean, you want an `Iterable` to only be iterated once, then what behaviour are you expecting upon a second iteration? An `OnlyOnceException` to be thrown?